# how to add random query parameter to success response of action

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, struts

> I have declared an action into struts action mapping area. we want to add random query parameter onto success.jsp page.is it possible like /home/success.jsp?id=10000

```
        <action path="/Signup" name="signupForm" type="signup.SignupAction"
            validate="true" input="/home/signup.jsp" scope="request">
            <forward name="login" path="/home/success.jsp" />
            <forward name="error" path="/home/signup.jsp" />
        </action>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would try is:

```
<forward name="login" path="/home/success.jsp?id=<%=id%>" />
```

or

```
<forward name="login" path="/home/success.jsp?id=${id}" />
```